# How to see how much data is queued up in a named pipe?

Tags: c, linux

In a Linux box, I have couple of processes writing to a named pipe and another one reading it. I am suspecting that my reader is not keeping up and there are lot of data queued up in the pipe.

Could anyone please tell me that, is there a way to check/see how much data is queued up in the pipe? Any Linux command or C API?

Thank you for your time.

--KS

Answer (score 1):

I don't think FIONREAD will work as FIONREAD is determined by the value returned by i_size_read which is stored in the inode as i_size.  i_size is not used with pipes (which is why stat always returns 0 for a pipe's size).

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h#L848

It should be possible to get the size by summing the len property of the buffers (i_node.i_pipe.bufs).  It doesn't look like this value is exposed by stat or ioctl though.

https://github.com/mirrors/linux-2.6/blob/master/fs/pipe.c

Answer (score 0):

You could try recv(..., MSG_PEEK) -- this should read from the pipe without removing the data from it (so the next read would return the same data).  It won't necessarily tell you about all the data queued, just some of it.